# Filter result with selectattr in an Ansible playbook

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to get the playbook show only the filtered result.
But instead it showing filtered and non-filtered result.
e.g: I just want it to show only the files that not owned by root in the output.

```yaml
- set_fact:
    target_file: /var/log/apache2/
  
- name: verify that the logs ownership/perms are belong to system administrators and service accounts.
  block: 

    - find: 
        paths: "{{ target_file }}"
        patterns: "*.log"
      register: ownership
      failed_when: ownership.files | selectattr('pw_name', '!=', 'root')

    - debug:
       var: ownership


    - find: 
        paths: "{{ target_file }}"
        patterns: "*.log"
      register: group
      failed_when: group.files | selectattr('gr_name', '!=', 'adm')

    - find: 
        paths: "{{ target_file }}"
        patterns: "*.log"
      register: permissions
      failed_when: permissions.files | selectattr('mode', '!=', '0640')

    - set_fact:
        stig_text: "PASSED"

  rescue:

    - name: change the permission and ownership of the files
      become: true
      file:
        path: "{{ item.path }}"
        owner: root
        group: adm
        mode: 0640
        with_items: "{{ ownership.files }}"
      register: change_perms

    - set_fact:
        stig_text: "PASSED"
      when: change_perms.changed == true
```

Debug output:

```
TASK [debug] ************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "ownership": {
        "changed": false,
        "examined": 18,
        "failed": false,
        "failed_when_result": false,
        "files": [
            {
                "atime": 1652373886.9567592,
                "ctime": 1652373886.9567592,
                "dev": 2,
                "gid": 0,
                "gr_name": "root",
                "inode": 3096224743982700,
                "isblk": false,
                "ischr": false,
                "isdir": false,
                "isfifo": false,
                "isgid": false,
                "islnk": false,
                "isreg": true,
                "issock": false,
                "isuid": false,
                "mode": "0644",
                "mtime": 1652373886.9567592,
                "nlink": 1,
                "path": "/var/log/alternatives.log",
                "pw_name": "root",
                "rgrp": true,
                "roth": true,
                "rusr": true,
                "size": 49270,
                "uid": 0,
                "wgrp": false,
                "woth": false,
                "wusr": true,
                "xgrp": false,
                "xoth": false,
                "xusr": false
            },
            {
                "atime": 1623178394.0,
                "ctime": 1652791696.643692,
                "dev": 2,
                "gid": 0,
                "gr_name": "root",
                "inode": 3377699720693451,
                "isblk": false,
                "ischr": false,
                "isdir": false,
                "isfifo": false,
                "isgid": false,
                "islnk": false,
                "isreg": true,
                "issock": false,
                "isuid": false,
                "mode": "0600",
                "mtime": 1623117753.0,
                "nlink": 1,
                "path": "/var/log/ubuntu-advantage.log",
                "pw_name": "root",
                "rgrp": false,
                "roth": false,
                "rusr": true,
                "size": 0,
                "uid": 0,
                "wgrp": false,
                "woth": false,
                "wusr": true,
                "xgrp": false,
                "xoth": false,
                "xusr": false
            }
        ],
        "matched": 6,
        "msg": ""
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code structure is a very strange and inefficient approach to this problem.

This is my best guess at what you were trying to do:

```yaml
- name: Verify the ownership and permissions on logs
  vars:
    target_file: /var/log/apache2/
  block:
    - name: Find all log files under {{ target_file }}
      find:
        paths: "{{ target_file }}"
        patterns: "*.log"
      register: log_files

    - name: Fix permissions and ownership
      file:
        path: "{{ item.path }}"
        owner: root
        group: adm
        mode: "0640"
      become: true
      loop: "{{ logs_bad_owner | union(logs_bad_group) | union(logs_bad_perms) }}"
      loop_control:
        label: "{{ item.path }}"
      vars:
        logs_bad_owner: "{{ log_files.files | selectattr('pw_name', '!=', 'root') }}"
        logs_bad_group: "{{ log_files.files | selectattr('gr_name', '!=', 'adm') }}"
        logs_bad_perms: "{{ log_files.files | selectattr('mode', '!=', '0640') }}"

    - set_fact:
        stig_text: PASSED

  rescue:
    - set_fact:
        stig_text: FAILED
```

This avoids unnecessary work like running the same `find` multiple times or looping over the entire set of files when you're only interested in the ones that need fixing.

Comment: My playbook structure is spitted into block and rescue sections.  The rescue section only run if the 'block' section is failed. According to your codes, it look like it does everything as once.

Comment: Yes, that's one of the things that makes your structure very strange. You used `rescue` for logic that's better handled by normal conditionals, and had a completely useless conditional on the final task in your rescue (there's no way to reach this `set_fact` without the previous task returning `changed`.) My answer is also split into `block` and `rescue`, but in a way that makes sense for the result that your code appears to be trying to achieve.

Comment: I got an error when executed the playbook: TASK [Fix permissions and ownership] ********************************************************************************************fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "Unexpected templating type error occurred on ({{ logs_bad_owner | union(logs_bad_group) | union(logs_bad_perms) }}): unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'set' and 'AnsibleUnsafeText'"}

Comment: It works for me; ending up with different types for one of the three identically processed variables suggests that you might have introduced a typo into one of them.

Comment: I double checked and there is no typo in your codes. Still getting the same error.

Comment: The tasks aren't executable due to the error from above. Is there a way to fix this ?

Answer (score 1):

Because your `debug` is just after a command that would fail if `pw_name` is not `root`, due to your `failed_when` condition, the `debug` just won't happen if there is any problematic file, and enters the rescue tasks instead, so when you do see the any debug task result, it means there was no problematic file, in terms on ownership, really.

Now the reason being pointed, you have to understand that Ansible is all about idempotency:

> An operation is idempotent if the result of performing it once is exactly the same as the result of performing it repeatedly without any intervening actions.

<sup>*Source: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/glossary.html*</sup>

So, you don't even have to do anything complex here you just have to set the rights and ownership to what it should:

```yaml
- name: change the permission and ownership of the files
  file:
    path: "{{ item }}"
    owner: root
    group: adm
    mode: 0640
  with_fileglob:
    - /var/log/apache2/*.log
  register: permission_audit
```

And then, if you want to make an audit report, you can do something like:

```yaml
- name: List of security remediation run during this audit
  debug:
    var: >-
      permission_audit.results 
      | selectattr('changed') 
      | map(attribute='diff')
```

Which would yield something like:

```
TASK [List of security remediation run during this audit] ********************
ok: [localhost] => 
  permission_audit.results | selectattr('changed') | map(attribute='diff'):
  - after:
      mode: '0640'
      path: /var/log/apache2/access.1.log
    before:
      mode: '0777'
      path: /var/log/apache2/access.1.log
  - after:
      mode: '0640'
      path: /var/log/apache2/access.2.log
    before:
      mode: '0777'
      path: /var/log/apache2/access.2.log
```

If you want to show the success or the failure of the audit in the result of the playbook you can even go one step further and `assert` the length of this list:

```yaml
- name: Security audit result
  assert:
    that: permission_changes | length == 0
    fail_msg: Audit on Apache log file rights failed
    success_msg: Audit on Apache log file rights passed
  vars:
    permission_changes: >-
      {{
        permission_audit.results
        | selectattr('changed')
        | map(attribute='diff')
      }}
```

And now our playbook will either end in

```
TASK [Security audit result] **********************************************
ok: [localhost] => changed=false 
  msg: Audit on Apache log file rights passed

PLAY RECAP ****************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

Or in

```
TASK [Security audit result] **********************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => changed=false 
  assertion: permission_changes | length == 0
  evaluated_to: false
  msg: Audit on Apache log file rights failed

PLAY RECAP ****************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=1
```

---

Given ten log files; two having rights issues and the two tasks:

```yaml
- file:
    path: "{{ item }}"
    owner: root
    group: adm
    mode: 0640
  with_fileglob:
    - /var/log/apache2/*.log
  register: permission_audit

- name: List of security remediation run during this audit
  debug:
    var: >-
      permission_audit.results
      | selectattr('changed')
      | map(attribute='diff')
```

This would yield:

```
TASK [file] *****************************************************************
changed: [localhost] => (item=/var/log/apache2/access.1.log)
ok: [localhost] => (item=/var/log/apache2/access.10.log)
ok: [localhost] => (item=/var/log/apache2/access.4.log)
ok: [localhost] => (item=/var/log/apache2/access.9.log)
ok: [localhost] => (item=/var/log/apache2/access.7.log)
ok: [localhost] => (item=/var/log/apache2/access.3.log)
ok: [localhost] => (item=/var/log/apache2/access.5.log)
ok: [localhost] => (item=/var/log/apache2/access.8.log)
ok: [localhost] => (item=/var/log/apache2/access.6.log)
changed: [localhost] => (item=/var/log/apache2/access.2.log)

TASK [List of security remediation run during this audit] *******************
ok: [localhost] => 
  permission_audit.results | selectattr('changed') | map(attribute='diff'):
  - after:
      mode: '0640'
      path: /var/log/apache2/access.1.log
    before:
      mode: '0777'
      path: /var/log/apache2/access.1.log
  - after:
      mode: '0640'
      path: /var/log/apache2/access.2.log
    before:
      mode: '0777'
      path: /var/log/apache2/access.2.log
```

And if you rerun those same two tasks again, then it ends up in:

```
TASK [file] *****************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=/var/log/apache2/access.1.log)
ok: [localhost] => (item=/var/log/apache2/access.10.log)
ok: [localhost] => (item=/var/log/apache2/access.4.log)
ok: [localhost] => (item=/var/log/apache2/access.9.log)
ok: [localhost] => (item=/var/log/apache2/access.7.log)
ok: [localhost] => (item=/var/log/apache2/access.3.log)
ok: [localhost] => (item=/var/log/apache2/access.5.log)
ok: [localhost] => (item=/var/log/apache2/access.8.log)
ok: [localhost] => (item=/var/log/apache2/access.6.log)
ok: [localhost] => (item=/var/log/apache2/access.2.log)

TASK [List of security remediation run during this audit] *******************
ok: [localhost] => 
  permission_audit.results | selectattr('changed') | map(attribute='diff'): []
```

Now, with an empty list on the last debug, we know our security audit passed everything with a green check.

Comment: This will not work. The `fileglob` lookup always runs on the controller, so you cannot use it to find files on the target.  (Also, using `find` makes this operation much more efficient, because you can avoid calling the `file` module when the permissions are already correct; for a handful of files this isn't a big deal, but if you're looping over hundreds the module overhead is significant.)

Comment: I don't need the debug task. I added it there for info purpose. This is a good approach.

Comment: I made a slight change to get the code to work:                                                        
   var: >-
      permission_audit.results
      | selectattr('changed')
      | map(attribute='diff') | list